# Powershell carriage return not working

Tags: powershell

```
$startTime = $(get-date)
write-host "`rElapsed:00:00:00"
$NoEvent = $true
While ($NoEvent)
{
  Start-Sleep 1
  $elapsedTime = new-timespan $startTime $(get-date)
  write-host "`rElapsed:$($elapsedTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss'))"
  #Handle event
  if(event){$NoEvent = $false}
}
```

I've tried running this in the ISE as well as through the regular console. The returns are never output.

Comment: do you want to return the elapse time on a new row or you want to replace the existing text with the new elapsed time?

Comment: replace the existing on the same line

Comment: From my understanding `r is a carriage return and should work the same as in other languages. A carriage return is a control character or mechanism used to reset a device's position to the beginning of a line of text. I'd rather not clear the entire screen because it would clear previous text that I would still like to be viewable.

Comment: You may find some way to kludge Write-Host with the -NoNewLine parameter and write [char]08 enough times to delete the time then re-write a new time. Really though, just use a progress bar...

Comment: I don't want to use a progress bar because I don't know before hand how long the task will take.

Comment: So just put the completion at 0% all the time and update the labels to show elapsed time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got it working using -NoNewLine switch

```
write-host -NoNewLine "`rElapsed:$($elapsedTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

`` `r `` only issues a CR, not a CR+LF (which is probably what you want). Use `` `n `` (‘newline’) instead.

Comment: I want it to output on the same line by overwriting

Comment: That's what `` `r `` should be doing; and when I've tried it, it does. What are you seeing?

Comment: I get the elapsed time output each after the other. `r has no effect

Comment: It works for me in PS4 and PS5.1 console; I get the behavior you describe with the PS5.1 ISE. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.1 ise and console. Build 4393 Revision 1532

Comment: You may have found a bug. I have 5.1.14409.1012

Comment: woops I meant build: 14393 I will try to update it and see if that fixes it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any PS cmdlet that can help with overwriting text from the same line unless you are clearing the entire window with `clear-host` or `cls`, but PowerShell has a built in `write-progress` cmdlet if that is something else you would want to consider.

You can try:

```
$startTime = $(get-date)
$NoEvent = $true
While ($NoEvent)
{

    for ($a=1; $a -lt 100; $a++) {

        Start-Sleep 1
        $elapsedTime = new-timespan $startTime $(get-date)

        Write-Progress -Activity "`rElapsed:$($elapsedTime.ToString('hh\:mm\:ss'))" -PercentComplete $a -CurrentOperation "$a% Processed" -Status "Please wait."

        #Handle event
        if(event){$NoEvent = $false}
    }
}
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Progress?view=powershell-5.1 for info on `write-progress`

and here is a related question: [PowerShell - Overwriting line written with Write-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846889/powershell-overwriting-line-written-with-write-host)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work for me because I'm intending to call it from a perl script that reads STDOUT and this does not appear to write directly to stdout and is also exiting automatically when it doesn't detect a console.

Comment: the information displayed before the elapsed time... can this be placed in a variable and be rewritten every time the elapsed time is written? If so, the `clear-host` way will work.

Comment: It turns out I just needed the -NoNewLine switch. Not sure why it was working for everyone else. Thanks anyways though.