# Windows Powershell shortcut to delete previous command's output

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

In the macOS terminal application (`Terminal.app`), there is a shortcut (`cmd+l`) to delete the previous command's output. Is there such a shortcut in Powershell?

Comment: `Ctrl-L` clears the console in both Windows and Linux. (Except in `cmd`, of course, but who cares about that old fossil...)

Comment: Look at the docs for `PSReadline`

Comment: I'm still looking for deleting the last command. control+L clears the entire host

Comment: @Amir I've used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232087/5039142) before to write multiple times to the same line. Without knowing the command you're looking to clear and the use case not sure if it's suitable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to clear screen in PowerShell, simply use the hot-key:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `Clear-History`. You can read more on it here: [Clear-History Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/clear-history?view=powershell-3.0). Added the link for powershell-v3.0 as you used that tag.

I guide you about how to create a shortcut for that command but it will be pretty much copy pasting the good stuff I found here: [Scripting Guy's Blog on creating Keyboard shortcut](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2008/11/03/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-add-a-windows-powershell-shortcut-to-the-quick-launch-toolbar/).

This will not delete the on-screen history. To delete the on screen history, you will need to use keyboard shortcut `Alt+F7`.

IMO, this should be all that you need.

Comment: No, what he's looking for is the - admittedly exotic - feature of only clearing the most recently executed command's _output_. The command itself remains in the history (in the standard macOS terminal).

Comment: yes! @mklement0 is right about what I'm looking for.