# why doesnt tee-object work with NoNewline?

Tags: powershell

i have the following function in my script

```
function Write-Host($object) 
{
    if($global:LogFile -eq $null)
    {
        $global:LogFile = $logFile
    }

    $object | tee $global:LogFile -Append
}
```

referencing this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847258/8397835

I am trying specifically this part here:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 }
while (($job.State -eq "Running") -and ($job.State -ne "NotStarted"))
{
    Write-Host ([char]9632) -NoNewLine
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

apparently, with tee, nonewline appears to be ignored...and without tee, i am getting the characters to display on one line as i am seeking

with tee:

[image: tee]

without tee

[image: without tee]

I think i know whats happening. since write-host is being converted to tee, any switches are ignored, be it color or in this case, nonewline. How can i make `nonewline` work with tee?

Comment: have you tried `Write-Output`?

Comment: @JoshE The term 'Write-Out' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: see my edit to use `Write-Output` - sorry, fat-fingered

Comment: @JoshE Write-Output doesnt have nonewline, so the characters are now being looped onto new lines

Comment: try using the `-NoEnumerate` parameter instead

Comment: @JoshE nope, same thing happened

Comment: @JoshE found a different way...[Console]::Write("$([char]9632)")

Comment: Your function does not have a parameter for `-NoNewLine`, how should it know what to do with that argument?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician parameter?

Comment: Your function has 1 parameter: `$object` so it only knows how to accept 1 argument. `Function Write-Host ($object){ ... }` is functionally the same as `Function Write-Host{ Param($object) ... }`, where `Param` is short for parameters, where you define what parameters your function accepts. You should really look up PowerShell Advanced Functions and read a blog post or two about them (like [this one](https://blog.ipswitch.com/advanced-powershell-functions-upping-game)).

Comment: @TheMadTechnician i understand now. so youre saying i should have another param like this: Param($object, (Mandatory=$false)$arg2)  ?. reason mandatory is false is because we dont want tof orce every single write-host throughout the scripts to include nonewline.

Comment: pretty close, but you want to name it appropriately, so more like `Param($object, [switch]$NoNewLine)`. You don't have to specify `Mandatory=$false`, that's the default. I also cast it as a switch, so it works just like the `Write-Host` cmdlet, and will default to false.

Comment: I would also strongly suggest against naming your function to be the same name as an existing cmdlet. It is only going to confuse people, especially people who are trying to help you here.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician nope, doesnt work. still seems to ignore the -NoNewLine

Comment: because it doesn't know what to do with it. `-NoNewLine` is a parameter for the cmdlet `Write-Host`, and the cmdlet has what to do with it written into the code. Your function doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195537/discussion-between-themadtechnician-and-cataster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195537/discussion-between-themadtechnician-and-cataster) I understand what you're trying to do. You want to write yourself a custom progress bar that both writes to a log file as well as to the console without line breaks in either. For that you can write a function that will accomplish it, but I do recommend picking a new name that doesn't conflict with an existing cmdlet. I'll use `Write-MyProgress`.

```
Function Write-MyProgress{ 
[cmdletbinding()] 
Param( 
    [parameter(valuefrompipeline=$true)]$message, 
    [switch]$NoNewLine 
)
    if($global:LogFile -eq $null) 
    { 
        $global:LogFile = $logFile 
    }
    Add-Content -Value $message -Path $LogFile -NoNewline:$NoNewLine
    Write-Host $Message -NoNewLine:$NoNewLine 
}
```

You could then call it explicitly:

```
Write-MyProgress ([char]9632) -NoNewLine
```

or pipe things to it:

```
[char]9632 | Write-MyProgress -NoNewLine
```

Or, if you don't want to use a function, you could just do it all with native cmdlets like in this example:

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    [char]9632 | Add-Content $LogFile -NoNewLine -PassThru | Write-Host -NoNewLine
    start-sleep -Sec 1
} -End {Add-Content -Value '' -Path $LogFile}
```

(Note that I add `''` to the log file at the end, so the log file gets a new line after the progress bar is done)

Comment: basing this off your last suggestion if i didnt wanna have a function, i found out that this is a shorter way to write to the file the progress bar without the -process and -end stuff, and ya it works! Add-Content $global:LogFile -Value ([char]9632) -NoNewLine -PassThru ........... :)
however, it appears to also be writing to the console? and it iterates new line on the console, but to the file its all on one line

Comment: basically, is there a way to make Add-Content NOT write to the console? besides | Write-Host -NoNewLine

Comment: Yeah, remove `-Passthru` from the `Add-Content` cmdlet. `Add-Content` by default does not output anything (unless there's an error). So delete `-PassThru | Write-Host -NoNewLine` from my example.

Comment: dude, this is amazing. [char]9632 | Add-Content $LogFile -NoNewLine -PassThru is all i needed :D Thank you so much for the explanations and breakdown and especially the detailed help!

Comment: Always happy to help a new scripter along their path. Thanks for being willing to learn and not just expect a handout!

Comment: of course! this enhances my cognitive scripting abilities, i dont usually take an answer and run with it, i always like going through many examples on posts and try to experiment with them on new sessions even if they are not my main objective, its just fun to learn new things that end up helping me in the future!