# Is there any way to avoid the line break when using Read-Host?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Powershell script for our support guys, to help them in their day to day tasks.
I have some experience with Powershell, but by far not a hardcore programmer.

I believe my question is fairly basic, even though I have not been able to find the exact answer yet.

```
function f_LOCAL_CheckADUser($strInitials)
{
    try
    {
        $TestVariable = Get-ADUser -Identity $strInitials -Properties *
        Write-Host " - approved" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host " - does not exist" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

$Internal_Initials = Read-Host " Enter initials"; f_LOCAL_CheckADUser $Internal_Initials
```

What is happening: The user enters someone’s initials (SamAccountName), the entry is then checked against our AD to see if the user exists, this is working just fine, but the “approve” / “does not exist” line is being printed on the line below what the user entered.

This is what it looks like now:

[image: Present outcome]

My question is then, is there any way to avoid the line break, and have the “approve” / “does not exist” be printed on the same line as where the user entered the input?

Would like it to be displayed like this:

[image: Desired outcome]

I have been searching far and wide, and actually found some inspiration on how to blank out a line and replace it with a new one, but that seems a little overkill. So I am hoping a simple solution may exist.

Inspiration: [PowerShell - Overwriting line written with Write-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846889/powershell-overwriting-line-written-with-write-host) credit to Boluwade Kujero for posting the reply.

Comment: `Read-Host` doesn't include newlines. Add a `throw` statement to your `catch` block to reveal _the actual error_, or print the value `$strInitials` to inspect what's really going on: `Write-Host "'$strInitials'"`

Comment: Hi Mathias
Thank you for your reply.
Regarding the 'Read-Host', I feared as much, since I couldn't find anything online about it. Regarding the actual error, I used a set of initials that I knew did not exist in our AD.

Comment: So it's working as expected? What exactly is the question here then? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I think he wants the read line being entered and the response on the same line
`Test - Approved` instead of `Test (NewLine) - Approved`

Comment: The functionality of testing whether or not the user exists works :), it is just the displayed result I was hoping to be able to print on one line instead of two.
I have edited my initial post, hope it makes more sense now. And sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Starting in PowerShell 5.1, virtual terminal (VT) escape sequences are now supported.  One form of escape sequence can move the cursor position, so long as the host supports it.  For example:

```
$esc = [char]27
$setCursorTop = "$esc[0;0H"

function f_LOCAL_CheckADUser($strInitials)
{
    $setCursorRight = "$esc[0;$(18 + $strInitials.length)H"
    try
    {
        $TestVariable = Get-ADUser -Identity $strInitials -Properties *
        Write-Host "${setCursorRight} - approved" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Host "${setCursorRight} - does not exist" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

Clear-Host
$Internal_Initials = Read-Host "${setCursorTop} Enter initials"
f_LOCAL_CheckADUser $Internal_Initials
```

...might give you the results you're looking for.

Other escape sequences may be more useful, if you wish to preserve screen information.  For more details on other supported VT escape sequences, visit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds very interesting, definitely something I will need to look into, thank you very much for the update.